# Returning parameters in Oracle SQL insert statements

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an insert statement which I need to return a parameter from in order to use it later.  I'm getting a strange error which I can't seem to find a solution for.  Can anyone shed any light on it?

```
set define off;
variable videoID number;

insert into VM_VIDEO (VIDEO_ID, ...)
  values (SEQ_VMMIGVIDEO_ID.NEXTVAL, ...)
  returning VIDEO_ID into :videoID;

insert into IMAGES (IMAGE_ID, ...)
  values (SEQ_IMAGE_ID.NEXTVAL, ...);

update VM_VIDEO
  set THUMB_IMAGE_ID = SEQ_IMAGE_ID.CURRVAL
  where VIDEO_ID = :videoID;
```

**Error:**

```
Error starting at line 4 in command:
insert into VM_VIDEO (VIDEO_ID, ...) values (SEQ_VMMIGVIDEO_ID.NEXTVAL, ...) returning VIDEO_ID into :videoID
Error report:
SQL Error: Not all return parameters registered
```

Comment: A SQL*Plus variable may not work here. Try a PL/SQL variable (DECLARE).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to put it into a PL/SQL block:

```
declare
  videoID number;
begin
  insert into VM_VIDEO (VIDEO_ID, ...)
    values (SEQ_VMMIGVIDEO_ID.NEXTVAL, ...)
    returning VIDEO_ID into videoID;

  insert into IMAGES (IMAGE_ID, ...)
    values (SEQ_IMAGE_ID.NEXTVAL, ...);

  update VM_VIDEO
    set THUMB_IMAGE_ID = SEQ_IMAGE_ID.CURRVAL
    where VIDEO_ID = videoID;
end;
```