# Why does this RETURNING INTO clause return an error?

Tags: c#, oracle

I am trying to perform an insert into an Oracle database table and return the newly created primary key (through a trigger and sequence).

I have one piece of code that works. I have a second piece of code that returns an error on ExecuteNonQuery().

I cannot for the life of me determine why the first code works and the second does not.

The first code that WORKS:

```
        string sqlStr = @"INSERT INTO LEI_EROUTER_SESSIONS(empCID, JOBNUMBER, EMP_NAME, LOGGEDON, MACHINENAME, IP) values(:empCID, :JOBNUMBER, :EMP_NAME, sysdate, :MACHINENAME, :IP) RETURNING C_ID INTO :LASTCID";

        int C_ID;

        using (RetryClass RetryClassInstance = new RetryClass(CallingForm, JobSessionData, UserData))
        {
            do
            {
                RetryClassInstance.Retry = false;
                C_ID = 0;
                OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(Machine_Data.oracle_connstr);
                OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sqlStr, conn);
                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("empCID", UserData.employee_cid);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("JOBNUMBER", JobSessionData.jobnumber);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("EMP_NAME", UserData.employee_name);
                    //cmd.Parameters.Add("LOGGEDON", DateTime.Now);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("MACHINENAME", Environment.MachineName);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("IP", GlobalFunctions.LocalIPAddress());
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("LASTCID", OracleDbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Output);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    C_ID = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["LASTCID"].Value.ToString());
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    RetryClassInstance.HadException(ex);
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (cmd != null) cmd.Dispose();
                    if (conn != null) conn.Dispose();
                }
            } while (RetryClassInstance.Retry == true);
        }

        return C_ID;
```

Here is the second piece of code that DOES NOT WORK:

```
        string C_ID;
        List<string> C_IDS = new List<string>();

        string sqlStr = @"INSERT INTO LEI_CHECKIN_QUEUE(CHECKIN_DATE, JOB_ID, CELL, SN, STEP_NAME, STEP_TYPE, START_SEQ,
                          END_SEQ, CHECKEDINBY_EMP_CID, IN_QUEUE, PRIORITY_CODE, STEP_STARTED_WHEN, GROUP_CID) 
                          VALUES(SYSDATE, :JOB_ID, :CELL, :SN, :STEP_NAME, :STEP_TYPE, :START_SEQ, :END_SEQ, :CHECKEDINBY_EMP_CID, 'Y', null, 
                          null, null) RETURNING C_ID INTO :LASTCID";

        using (RetryClass RetryClassInstance = new RetryClass(this, JobSessionData, UserData))
        {
            do
            {
                RetryClassInstance.Retry = false;
                OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(Machine_Data.oracle_connstr);
                OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sqlStr, conn);
                try
                {
                    conn.Open();

                    foreach (string SN in JobSessionData.serial_numbers)
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("JOB_ID", JobSessionData.jobnumber);
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("CELL", JobSessionData.cell);
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("STEP_NAME", StepName);
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("STEP_TYPE", StepType);
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("START_SEQ", Start_Seq);
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("END_SEQ", End_Seq);
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("CHECKEDINBY_EMP_CID", UserData.employee_cid);
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("SN", SN);
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("LASTCID", OracleDbType.Int64, ParameterDirection.Output);

                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        C_ID = cmd.Parameters["LASTCID"].Value.ToString();
                        C_IDS.Add(C_ID);
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    RetryClassInstance.HadException(ex);
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (cmd != null) cmd.Dispose();
                    if (conn != null) conn.Dispose();
                }
            } while (RetryClassInstance.Retry == true);
        }
```

The error returned from the second piece of code is as follows:

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   at OracleInternal.TTC.TTCExecuteSql.ReceiveExecuteResponse(Accessor[]& defineAccessors, Accessor[] bindAccessors, Boolean bHasReturningParams, SQLMetaData& sqlMetaData, SqlStatementType statementType, Int64 noOfRowsFetchedLastTime, Int32 noOfRowsToFetch, Int32& noOfRowsFetched, Int64& queryId, Int32 longFetchSize, Int32 initialLOBFetchSize, Int64[] scnFromExecution, Boolean& bAllPureInputBinds, DataUnmarshaller& dataUnmarshaller, MarshalBindParameterValueHelper& marshalBindParamsHelper, Boolean bDefineDone, Boolean& bMoreThanOneRowAffectedByDmlWithRetClause)
   at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleCommandImpl.ExecuteNonQuery(String commandText, OracleParameterCollection paramColl, CommandType commandType, OracleConnectionImpl connectionImpl, Int32 longFetchSize, Int32 lobPrefetchSize, OracleDependencyImpl orclDependencyImpl, Int64[]& scnFromExecution, OracleParameterCollection& bindByPositionParamColl, Boolean& bBindParamPresent, Boolean isFromEF)
   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Both are run on the same Oracle database instance. And the second piece of code works fine if I comment out the lines pertaining to the OUTPUT PARAMETER and remove the returning clause from the SQL INSERT statement.

Also, the LEI_CHECKIN_QUEUE table DOES have a column named C_ID which is the primary key.

Does anyone have any clues about why the second piece of code is not working and/or what I can do to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tested your query directly on the Oracle without c# code?

Comment: When I try to do so I get the following: SQL Error: Not all return parameters registered. I am not sure what this means.

Comment: Even if someone can help me understand why an "Index out of bounds" error has anything to do with what my code is doing, that would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: See this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12105669/returning-parameters-in-oracle-sql-insert-statements  Basically, your SQL code needs to be in a block and the return variable needs to be defined.

Comment: Thanks Grant for the edit. I am still learning!

Comment: Running on Oracle directly using SQL Dev  inserts a record properly.

Comment: What is the difference between these two? Just a datatype of returned id? I'm not familiar with C#, but in case of Java there is a problem, that RETURNING clause is Oracle's proprietary extension and therefore it can not be supported by JDBC standard. So people have to wrap INSERT into anonymous PL/SQL block. Also you should use something like BigDecimal for IDs, it will be faster and also safer - Oracle NUMBER can be bigger than int64.

Comment: It also looks like the 1st case respects the order of bind variable names in the SQL statement, while the 2nd one does not. `SN` should be the 3rd. I do not know if it matters or not. Internally (in OCI) there are OCIBindByName and OCIBindByNumber functions.

Comment: @NotMe - Thanks! Your comment was correct and proved to be the answer as Dan gave me below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to declare the variable as shown below. 
As a rule of thumb, always test your query on the Oracle server before you embed it into your code. Most, importantly use parametrized Store Procedures to avoid sql injection attacks. So Do not embed queries into your code.

```
@"declare   LASTCID number;
INSERT INTO LEI_CHECKIN_QUEUE(CHECKIN_DATE, JOB_ID, CELL, SN, STEP_NAME, STEP_TYPE, START_SEQ,
                          END_SEQ, CHECKEDINBY_EMP_CID, IN_QUEUE, PRIORITY_CODE, STEP_STARTED_WHEN, GROUP_CID) 
                          VALUES(SYSDATE, :JOB_ID, :CELL, :SN, :STEP_NAME, :STEP_TYPE, :START_SEQ, :END_SEQ, :CHECKEDINBY_EMP_CID, 'Y', null, 
                          null, null) RETURNING C_ID INTO :LASTCID";
```

Comment: My first code block runs and has nothing as such. I am using an INSERT statement with returning clause.

Comment: did you try the above solution?

Comment: Call me set-in-my-ways for not being willing to believe something I have never seen done before. Thank you Mr. Dan Hunex for your answer which worked -- much to my joy! I RARELY ask for help since I pride myself on being able to figure out things for myself. So when I posted this question it was because I was TRULY stuck! I had tried for hours to make it work! Thank you Dan! Now I can move on with my project!

Comment: Can anyone explain WHY "declare   LASTCID number;" is needed in this example to work...yet I have truly had other examples that worked without having to declare the return parameter in the SQL code?

Comment: I just ran into this and I have no idea what is going on either. I ran identical code against 3 oracle servers that are supposed to be identical. 2 work fine without the declare, then the 3rd fails until I add it. Thanks for raising this--I would have been troubleshooting for a lot longer without this thread.

Answer (score 1):

It's an old post but [Dan Hunex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29660204/210916) helped me figure my problem out. I had to be a bit more formal, using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, but essentially my problem was the same and your query would have looked like this in my case:

```
DECLARE
    LASTCID number;
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO LEI_CHECKIN_QUEUE(CHECKIN_DATE, JOB_ID, CELL, SN, STEP_NAME, STEP_TYPE, START_SEQ,
                      END_SEQ, CHECKEDINBY_EMP_CID, IN_QUEUE, PRIORITY_CODE, STEP_STARTED_WHEN, GROUP_CID) 
                      VALUES(SYSDATE, :JOB_ID, :CELL, :SN, :STEP_NAME, :STEP_TYPE, :START_SEQ, :END_SEQ, :CHECKEDINBY_EMP_CID, 'Y', null, 
                      null, null) RETURNING C_ID INTO :LASTCID;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you made some extra unneeded parameter

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("SN", SN);
```

Good habit is an initialisation of OracleCommand with "BindByName = true"
Something like

```
using (OracleCommand countCommand = new OracleCommand(strSql, connection) { CommandType = CommandType.Text, BindByName = true })
{...}
```

Comment: My paramaters were out of order, but SN was in the query...you must have missed it.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. But you pass values for the parameters not in the same order as the placeholders in the query. Change the order or use BindByName = true.

Answer (score 0):

when you use "@" in each line is concatenated  "\n" so your resulting string would

```
"INSERT INTO LEI_CHECKIN_QUEUE(CHECKIN_DATE, JOB_ID, CELL, SN,  \n STEP_NAME, STEP_TYPE, START_SEQ, END_SEQ, CHECKEDINBY_EMP_CID, \n IN_QUEUE, PRIORITY_CODE, STEP_STARTED_WHEN, GROUP_CID) \n VALUES(SYSDATE, :JOB_ID, :CELL, :SN, :STEP_NAME, :STEP_TYPE, \n :START_SEQ, :END_SEQ, :CHECKEDINBY_EMP_CID, 'Y', null, null, null) \n RETURNING C_ID INTO :LASTCID";
```

You should use

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO LEI_CHECKIN_QUEUE (CHECKIN_DATE, JOB_ID, CELL, SN, STEP_NAME, STEP_TYPE, START_SEQ,";
sql += "END_SEQ, CHECKEDINBY_EMP_CID, IN_QUEUE, PRIORITY_CODE, STEP_STARTED_WHEN, GROUP_CID)";
sql += "VALUES (SYSDATE,: JOB_ID,: CELL: SN: STEP_NAME,: STEP_TYPE,: START_SEQ,: END_SEQ,: CHECKEDINBY_EMP_CID, 'Y', null,";
sql += "null, null) C_ID RETURNING INTO: LASTCID";
```

Comment: I do not see the problem in having new lines in the query text, why do you think this is problem please ?